# jQuery filter plugin with search

Tags: jquery

I'm after a jQuery plugin that filters div's depending on the users in-putted search. The closest I can find is http://www.mixitup.io/ and http://razorjack.net/quicksand/ they can filter just like I wanted but they don't have the option to filter on user input in a text field.

Its ok actually I will write my own based on this http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/ looks like I was searching fro the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a plugin needed for that just do something like.

```
$('.submitbutton_class').on("click", function(e){
    //e.preventDefault(); if needed
    $.each($('div'), function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf( $("input.theOneYouWant").val() )>-1){
            //do something
        }
    });
});
```

But if you must, maybe try [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) sort and switch up the markup from divs to tables.

Answer (score 0):

Its ok actually I will write my own based on this http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/ looks like I was searching fro the wrong thing.